# encode and decode with multiple strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, character-encoding, base64

In one of my task, I need to encode the data while sending and decode the data at the receiving end.

```
Encoding : Buffer.from("bob" + "carl").toString('base64');
Decoding : Buffer.from(<encoded-string>,'base64').toString('ascii'));
```

As you can see, I am encoding here 2 strings('bob' and 'carl'). Is there any way that while decoding we get as 2 separate strings?

Comment: What, you expect the decoder to automagically know where you want it to split the output strings? No, that's not possible. Encode them and decode them separately if you want them separately.

Comment: @Patrick: I am sure that decoder cannot split the output strings as it doesn't know the end/start of multiple strings. However, is there a way to encode multiple strings at one go and I can identify the multiple strings while decoding?

Comment: `arrayOfEncodedStrings = ["bob", "carl"].map(string => Buffer.from(string, 'ascii').toString('base64'))` and `arrayOfDecodedStrings = arrayOfEncodedStrings.map(string => Buffer.from(string, 'base64').toString('ascii'))`?

Comment: @Patrick: arrayOfEncodedStrings will actually contain multiple encoded strings. This is not what I am looking. Resultant encoded string must be one string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a highly unique string to act as the delimiter and then use a split with the matching delimiter on the other side.

For example:

```
delimiter = "~~~"
```

Encoding

```
Buffer.from("bob" + delimiter + "carl").toString('base64');
```

Decoding

```
decode = Buffer.from(<encoded-string>,'base64').toString('ascii')).split(delimiter);
decode[0] == "bob";
decode[1] == "carl";
```

Comment: Kool. This seems to be one possible way. Are there any others? I am looking for various possible options because, I may need to send this encoded string in a URL and in different ways.

Comment: I would recommend to use a control character as delimiter (especially if you know that original strings will not have control characters, which should be the case, but for the few obvious one (new line, tab). U+0003 (End-Of-Text) seems a good choice.

Comment: @Bobby It has been two weeks since I gave you the answer, which you have acknowledged as being correct. You should accept it or provide more clarification of what else you are looking for other than saying "different ways".